# How to recover data off of a broken linux system with full-disk encryption

Tags: data-recovery, luks, glibc, disk-encryption

I am running Manjaro. I have it set up with full-disk encryption through LUKS. Booting up my computer I noticed some things were weird, like some of my settings had reverted to their default. I tried to write some code but gcc didn't work because it couldn't find GLIBC_2.38. I installed it through pacman and did a full system upgrade, which fixed it for gcc. Today, I went to turn my computer back on and it's broken.

- I *can* get into the bios menu and boot from a USB, etc.
- I can't get into grub, even by holding shift.
- I don't get prompted to type in my disk encryption password. It breaks before it gets to that point.

When I try to boot up, I get what you can see below. This is hand transcribed, so I may have mis-typed some part.

```
systemd-tmpfiles: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-253.8-1.so)
udevadm: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by udevadm)
udevadm: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-253.8-1.so)
udevadm: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by udevadm)
udevadm: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-253.8-1.so)
udevadm: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by udevadm)
udevadm: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-253.8-1.so)
ERROR: Failed to open encryption mapping: The device UUID=9b197f47-4e6a-4a00-bc5a-0d50ca8e272 is not a LUKS volume and the crypto= parameter was not specified.
ERROR: resume: hibernation device '/dev/disk/by-uuid/293272c3-fbcc-4c6b-b9b8-703a4204bec4' not found
ERROR: device 'UUID=293272c3-fbcc-4c6b-b9b8-703a4204bec4' not found, Skipping fsck.
mount: /new_root: can't find UUID=293272c3-fbcc-4c6b-b9b8-703a4204bec4.
ERROR: Failed to mount 'UUID=293272c3-fbcc-4c6b-b9b8-703a4204bec4' on real root
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ~]#
```

I understand this is probably my fault messing with GLIBC, but right now I'd just like to recover my data. Luckily all the really important stuff is backed up, but there's still some things on the drive that I haven't backed up that I'd like to get back. I remember my password, I just need a way to run the decryption on the drive and copy the data over to my external hard-disk. Or if there's a way to fix the whole thing, that would be great too.

Comment: was `You are not being dropped into an emergency shell.` actually saying `You are NOW being dropped into an emergency shell.`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've edited the post and fixed it.

Comment: so what happens if you try from a livecd / rescue environment? in some cases all you have to do is chroot and rebuild the initramfs. backup your files as soon as you have access to them though

Comment: I've tried booting into Rescatux in normal mode using YUMI without persistence. I use the autodetect live system, and after a short boot sequence it logs me into Debian automatically, gives met the `absolutely no warranty` message, and then hangs.